# Ubuntu 18.04 occasional "Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on Hyper-V and I occasionally encounter freezes in internet connection.

Like I have ping to `google.com` or `8.8.8.8` running for an hours and then it suddenly stops.

If I terminate process and run it again I get `Temporary failure in name resolution` after couple seconds of waiting. Then after some time (maybe a minute or a half) it comes back to live. Sometimes it comes back only for couple seconds and then goes away for another few but at the end after couple minutes it starts to work just fine.

While this freez persist I can not connect to that maschine from the outside - no connection to a web server or with SSH - even though I’m able to connect to it from my laptop via Hyper-V (that is how I see the ping status).

I’m quite new in the server or Linux world but our administrator couldn't help me so I have to face it by myself. I have no idea what should I check to get an even faint sense of what is going on.

The server is running inside company’s local subnetwork and this is the config file `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses:
            - 10.55.40.111/24
            gateway4: 10.55.40.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 10.55.50.57
                - 8.8.8.8
    version: 2
```

DNS is correct and everything inside the company is working with it.

I even have exactly the same Virtual Machine on small backup computer on my desk (only with different IP and gateway - `10.55.50.111`, `10.55.50.1`) and overthere it all seems to work all the time.

The 3rd octet is for subnetworks (40 is for servers and 50 is for normal employee computers).

I need to find root cause to fix it myself or explain to our administrator what is wrong. I really appreciate any help and sorry for my lack of knowledge in the topic.

Comment: could you add the output of an "ip route" "ip link" and "systemd-resolve --status" to your question please?